# SELECT with aggregate function in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE cheque
  (
    ch_id          NUMBER NOT NULL ,
    ch_price       VARCHAR2 (100) ,
    ch_customer    NUMBER NOT NULL
  ) ;
ALTER TABLE cheque ADD CONSTRAINT check_PK PRIMARY KEY ( ch_id ) ;

CREATE TABLE customer
  (
    cus_id      NUMBER NOT NULL ,
    cus_name    VARCHAR2 (100) ,
  ) ;
ALTER TABLE customer ADD CONSTRAINT customer_PK PRIMARY KEY ( cus_id ) ;

ALTER TABLE cheque ADD CONSTRAINT check_customer_FK FOREIGN KEY ( ch_customer ) REFERENCES customer ( cus_id );
```

How to get SUM of prices in cheque for each customers? For example, if I had a customer John and 3 cheque records for him with ch_price 10, 20 and 30, I would have to get John - 60.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
Select cus_name, sum(ch_price) 
from customer, cheque
where cheque_customer=cus_id;
```

Comment: You have tagged this question with the name of 3 different database products. Which are you actually using?

Comment: I think `Oracle` by the data type `VARCHAR2`

Comment: It's oracle but I don't think it really matters

Comment: Why is ch_price a VARCHAR2?

Comment: It's ok if varchar2 value can be converted into number, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @user2246018 - when it can, maybe; but there is nothing stopping someone putting in something that cannot be converted, and then your queries will suddenly start failing. You should alway use the correct data type for the data that s going to be stored. Never store numbers or dates as strings. (I'd also recommend you use ANSI join syntax - if you are new to this, no point starting out with bad habits *8-)

Comment: "it didn't work" is not an error message. Please _always_ include the actual error message. If you'd have searched on it you'd have found your answer almost immediately...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
Select cus_name, sum(ch_price) as Total
from customer, cheque
where cheque_customer=cus_id
group by cus_name
```